# Does a flame put off a windlike force

Tags: home-experiment

When I hold a flame above a flame the one on top flickers and waves as if its about to go out. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Can you provide some substantial snapshots of your experiment?

Answer (score 2):

Flame produces hot gas flowing upwards and blowing the flame on top.

Comment: That explains the waving, but not necessarily the flame flickering as if its about to go out.  The truth is likely a combination of yours and @Shua's.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the top flame is being robbed of its oxygen by the bottom flame.